# Javascript scoping issue while using Async Await in (for ... of) loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, async-await

**Case:** I have a list of 20 items (clients) on a page where I want to grab some info via API about each item (client); that will end up sending 20 requests for each page load even if the item (client) is duplicated/repeated (item could repeat 20 a page; that's 20 request for the same item)

**What I wanna achieve:** 2 things:

1. To Send only to uniques without repeating. ***DONE*** *using* `new Set()`
2. To iterate through all the items but wait ***(stop looping)*** (if a request was sent) till it resolves and returns the required data `clientPhone`.

**What I achieved:** It logs all in sequence but `console.log(clientPhone)` works only in the request function `getAllCients()`, not in others, even though I assigned it to global variable.

**What I did:**

```
<script>
    async function getAllClients (clientName, clientCode){
        console.log("fired!")
        await $.get("/api/clients", data => {
            console.log(data)
            data.data.map(async (val) => {
                val = val.Client
                let name = $.trim(val.business_name);
                let code = $.trim(val.client_number);
                if (name == clientName && code == clientCode) {
                    clientPhone = await val.phone2
                    console.log(clientPhone) //logs *clients' phone*
                    return clientPhone

                }
            })
        })
    }



    async function myApp() {
        let clientSet = new Set()
        for (const [i, v] of Array.from($(".media-body")).entries()) {
            let clientName = $.trim($(v).find("h3").text())

            if (!clientSet.has(clientName)) {
                clientSet.add(clientName)
                clientPhone = await getAllClients(clientName)
                console.log("------", clientPhone) //logs *undefined*
                // Do some other functions
            } else {
                console.log(clientPhone) //logs *undefined*
                // Do some other functions
            }
        }
    }

    //=============== App starts ================ 

    $(document).ready(function () {
        let clientPhone;
        
        myApp()
})
</script>
```

**In A Nutshell:** I want to store the `clientPhone` in its global variable for each iteration a request is sent to reuse its value for other items that repeat.

Comment: Use the Promise from `$.get` alone, not the callback form - then, return the result of the `.map` call

Comment: That was my bad. didn't notice that `return` is scoped in the `.map` .. Just moved it out to the parent function scope and worked as it should.